# Random linq result

Tags: linq, random

I have this LINQ query:

var agnts = (from a in db.agents select new { a.UserId, a.name }).Take(10);

How can I get randomly get 10 records from my agents table?

I have tried:

agnts = agnts.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid());

but this doesn't seem to do anything.

I would appreciate anybody's help on this.

Thanks,

Louis

Answer (score 1):

Then you do

```
agnts = agnts.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid());
```

after

```
var agnts = (from a in db.agents select new { a.UserId, a.name }).Take(10);
```

agents are already taken. You need to specify OrderBy() before Take()